# Haystack SearchQuerySet won't filter on a CharField with one character (Whoosh / django-haystack)

Tags: python, django, filter, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm using Django 1.5.1 with django-haystack 2.1.0 and the whoosh 2.5.2 backend:

**models.py:**

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    (u'M', u'Male'),
    (u'F', u'Female'),
)

class Applicant(models.Model):

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

**search_indexes.py:**

```
class ApplicantIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):

    text = indexes.CharField(document=True,use_template=True)
    gender = indexes.CharField(model_attr="gender")
```

**search template**

```
{{ object.first_name }}
{{ object.last_name }}
```

In the django shell i'm trying following:

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

>>> sqs=SearchQuerySet()
>>> sqs
[<SearchResult: tooldb.applicant (pk=u'1')>, <SearchResult: tooldb.applicant (pk=u'2')>]

>>> sqs[0].gender
u'M'     #<-- So this seems to be indexed

#but when i try:
>>> sqs.filter(gender='M')
[]     #<-- I get nothing ... ?
```

I tried it with other CharFields without choices and max_lenght > 1, no problem at all, haystack filters like it should.

What am I missing?

Comment: QuerySet's filter method works fine with one character as query, SearchQuerySet just returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
class ApplicantIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    gender = indexes.CharField()

    def prepare_gender(self, obj):
        return obj.gender*3
```

Now you can filter like:

```
sqs.filter(gender='MMM')
```

Comment: seems like a workaround.. although kinda dirty. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay i think i got it..

It seems like haystack in combination with whoosh doesn't work with single char queries **at all**.
This is kind of annoying cause SearchQuerySet should be implemented in the way Django's QuerySet works. (https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/searchqueryset_api.html#why-follow-queryset)

QuerySet's filter method works fine with one character as query, SearchQuerySet just returns nothing.

This should be documented somewhere...